# Truecrypt alternative with deniable encryption?

Tags: software-recommendation, encryption, alternative, truecrypt, open-source

I am looking for a Truecrypt alternative for Linux, one that is preferably is free/libre/open-source software (FLOSS).

I would have used Truecrypt, but it has been discontinued.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, what you want or need. Please [edit] your question to clarify this point. There are a few successors to TrueCrypt. Some break compatibility, some don't. Current versions of `cryptsetup` also support reading the most popular TrueCrypt setups. You can also use pure `dm-crypt` volumes or use a container for them like LUKS. As the last option you can continue to use TrueCrypt, since there is no known vulnerability or serious flaw in it.